# unexpected ...options in sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, docker, sequelize.js, amazon-ecs

i would like to dockerize node js app into AWS ECS and in development it's working normally.
but once want to dockerize them it's returning error on provider file:

```
/srv/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:277
  ...options
  ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/sequelize/index.js:8:18)
```

is there any way for me to dockerize them without the error? because without sequelize the node app can be dockerize properly

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using in dockerized container?

Comment: v10-15-3 -@Mansur

Answer (score 0):

Check version of your nodejs and sequelize, if not support together, use this code for update your node version:

- sudo yum install nodejs
- node --version
- npm --version
- which node
- which npm
- curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
- ls -la /etc/yum.repos.d/|grep nodesource
- sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm
- sudo yum list available nodejs
- sudo yum install nodejs
- node --version
- npm --version

Answer (score 0):

I have my nodejs app running in a docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:7.4.0
```

Node:

```sh
/usr/src/app # node --version
v7.4.0
```

I upgraded my node image and the problem was solved.

New Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:16
```

Node:

```sh
/usr/src/app # node --version
v16.4.2
```

No more errors.